# Comparing MSE of two estimators

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\hat{\theta}_1$ be an estimator of $\theta$, which is known to lie in the interval $(a,b)$.

Define an estimator of $\theta$, $\hat{\theta}_2$, by $\hat{\theta}_2=\hat{\theta}_1$ if $\hat{\theta}_1 \in (a,b)$, $\hat{\theta}_2 =a$ if $\hat{\theta}_1 \leq a$, and $\hat{\theta}_2 =b$ if $\hat{\theta}_1 \geq b$. Prove that MSE($\hat{\theta}_2$) $\leq$ MSE($\hat{\theta}_1$). If $\hat{\theta}_1$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, also show that Var($\hat{\theta}_2$) $\leq$ Var($\hat{\theta}_1$).

I think this problem should be easy. By intuition (for the first question), bias($\hat{\theta}_2$)$\leq$ bias($\hat{\theta}_1$) since $\text{E}[\hat{\theta}_2]$ should be closer to $\theta$ in every of 3 conditions above. I have tried as follows:

Let $f_{\hat{\theta}_1} (x)$ be the pdf of $\hat{\theta}_1$. Then
\begin{align*}
\text{bias}(\hat{\theta}_2)=\text{E}[\hat{\theta}_2]-\theta&=\hat{\theta}_1 P(X \in (a,b)) + a P(X \leq a) + b P(X \geq b)\\
&=\left( \hat{\theta}_1 \int\limits_{a}^{b}f_{\hat{\theta}_1}(x)dx + a \int\limits_{-\infty}^{a}f_{\hat{\theta}_1}(x)dx + b \int\limits_{b}^{\infty}f_{\hat{\theta}_1}(x)dx \right) -\theta
\end{align*}
while
\begin{align*}
\text{bias}(\hat{\theta}_1)=\text{E}[\hat{\theta}_1]-\theta
&= \left( \int\limits_{a}^{b}xf_{\hat{\theta}_1}(x)dx +  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{a}xf_{\hat{\theta}_1}(x)dx +  \int\limits_{b}^{\infty}xf_{\hat{\theta}_1}(x)dx \right) -\theta
\end{align*}
But then I don't know what to do to compare those two bias. Am I on the wrong track? Any help I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left((\hat{\theta}_2-\theta)^2|\hat{\theta}_1 \in (a,b)\right)= \mathbb{E}\left((\hat{\theta}_1-\theta)^2|\hat{\theta}_1 \in (a,b)\right),\;(1)\\
\mathbb{E}\left((\hat{\theta}_2-\theta)^2|\hat{\theta}_1 \notin (a,b)\right) \leq \mathbb{E}\left((\hat{\theta}_1-\theta)^2|\hat{\theta}_1 \notin (a,b)\right).\;(2)
\end{equation}
Then, by the law of total expectation, 
\begin{align}
\textrm{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_2)&\triangleq\mathbb{E}\left((\hat{\theta}_2-\theta)^2\right)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\hat{\theta}_1 \in (a,b)\right)\mathbb{E}\left((\hat{\theta}_2-\theta)^2|\hat{\theta}_1 \in (a,b)\right)+\\
&\mathbb{P}\left(\hat{\theta}_1 \notin (a,b)\right)\mathbb{E}\left((\hat{\theta}_2-\theta)^2|\hat{\theta}_1 \notin (a,b)\right)\\
\end{align}
Applying (1), (2) will give you the result.

EDIT: Concerning the variance result, note that for any variable $x$ (verify) 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left((x-\mathbb{E}(x))^2\right) \leq \mathbb{E}\left((x-y)^2\right), \; \forall y\neq \mathbb{E}(x)
\end{equation}
Therefore, $\textrm{Var}(\hat{\theta}_2) \leq \textrm{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_2) \leq \textrm{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_1) =  \textrm{Var}(\hat{\theta}_1)$, where the last equality is a property of any unbiased estimator (verify).

Comment: Thank you so much now I get the idea. And the $$\text{E}\left( (\hat{\theta}_2-\text{E}(\hat{\theta}_2))^2|\hat{\theta}_1 \notin (a,b)\right)=0$$ that's why the variance of the latter estimator is smaller or equal the first one.

Comment: The variance result follows by noting that, when the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is unbiased, it holds MSE($\hat{\theta}$)$=$Var$(\hat{\theta})$

Comment: Please see the edited answer concerning the variance result